# Kentico twitter feed

Tags: twitter, kentico

Hi I am struggling to get a Twitter feed into a web part on Kentico 8.2 that excludes images and has only the last feed visible.  I have managed to embed the last feeds with images but this is too large for my page.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of a service like this one:

https://twitrss.me/

It processes your tweets as RSS feed and you can load them using **RSS data source** web part and render them (or just the first one) using the **Basic repeater** web part.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this service if I were you. Its not a serious tool. Just like all the other hacks to get data from twitter without using the official API its liable to break any time.

The author also says the tool is not serious, and that it works by scraping the HTML of the feed.

https://twitrss.me/#about